# Run perl Plackup script from Scheduled Task

Tags: perl, windows-task-scheduler, plack

**How can I call a script with that preceding argument before the script path using Task Scheduler or a batch file? `plackup E:\Mojolicious_server.pl`**

So I have multiple Mojolicious applications.
I have bundled them all into a psgi server using plack.

My plack script looks like this...

```
use Plack::Builder;
use lib 'push_the_button/lib';
use lib 'Phone_Book/lib';

use Mojo::Server::PSGI;
use Plack::Session::Store;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

my $current_directory = dirname(__FILE__);

my $push_the_button, $phone_book;


{
  my $server_1 = Mojo::Server::PSGI->new;
  $server_1->load_app($current_directory.'/Phone_Book/script/application');
  $phone_book = sub { $server_1->run(@_) }
}

{
  my $server_2 = Mojo::Server::PSGI->new;
  $server_2->load_app($current_directory.'/push_the_button/script/push_the_button.pl');
  $push_the_button = sub { $server_2->run(@_) }
}

builder {

  mount "/phone_book" => builder {$phone_book};
  mount "/push_the_button" => builder {$push_the_button};
};
```

Now I want to run this as a scheduled task at system startup.

to run this script normally, I would go to cmd 
`pushd c:\strawberry\perl\bin`

Then I would run this command

`plackup E:/Mojolicious_Server.pl`

My issue seems to be that `plackup` portion. 
I have tried adding `plackup E:/Mojolicious_Server.pl` to the Arguments portion. I have also tried adding `plackup` to the arguments portion and `E:/Mojolicious_Server.pl` in the start in portion. Of course `C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe` is the Program to start.

Once I tried all the variations I could think of (including variations on double and single quotes), I wrote a very simple batch file to run (even just in the terminal for testing). It looks like this.

```
@echo off

call "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "plackup E:\Mojolicious_Server.pl"
```

Which says "Can't open perl script".

I went ahead and tried another route using another perl script to **execute** my command...

```
#! C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

`plackup E:\\Mojolicious_Server.pl`;
```

This at least completes successfully in the Task Scheduler, doesn't actually do anything though...

Just as a last resort (obviously wouldn't work), I added `plackup E:\\Mojolicious_Server.pl`; at the end of my Mojolicious_Server.pl script and run that script. Didn't work as I expected (calling a script thats already running).

This seems like it should be very easy, I'm sorry if I'm missing something simple. Any notion in the right direction would be appreciated.

Also I am only doing it this way because I am strictly on a windows environment. If there is a better way, again, please just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know what your `PATH` variable is like for scheduled processes? I would try `<full path>/plackup E:/Mojolicious_Server.pl`.

Comment: Hmm you know I'm not sure. Definitely worth looking into though! I'll see what I can find. I'll be back with results. Thanks!

Comment: @JavierElices Okay so I found my `plackup` path which is `c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\plackup` I can run `c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\plackup E:\Mojolicious_server` from the command line and it works! But from the Task Scheduler I get a "0x1" error... seems like the right direction, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference was from the first time I tried it but you were exactly correct. Solved by making my argument `c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\plackup E:\Mojolicious_server.pl`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments of the question, all it takes is to invoke the sequence `plackup E:/Mojolicious_Server.pl` making sure that you add the full path to the `plackup` script. In the case of @gregnnylf94, it was:

```
c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\plackup E:\Mojolicious_server.pl
```

This is so because *cron* jobs do not have the same context as *shell* ones. The most frequent problem comes from the `PATH` variable that is key to finding what you want to execute.

This is true in Windows and Linux systems alike.